# simplehtmldom - follow links

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Can someone show an example how to follow links for each elements `<a href>` while scraping and get its related info ?

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.blabla.com/');
$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';
```

Now each `<li>` has a link to more info

```
<li class="#Selected">
<a href="/contactinfo/ITService/">info</a>
<h2>New York</h2>
<h3>USA</h3>
<strong>ITService</strong>
</li>
```

Then :

```
<div class="InfoD">
<h2>New York</h2>
<h3>USA</h3>
<strong>ITService</strong>
<p>
Tel. : XXXXXX   
</p>
<p>
Mail. : XXXX@XXX.com    
</p>
</div>
```

I know how to scrape such elements using HTML DOM but when there are links for each elements and multiple pages, I am not sure how to..If anyone can point to an example or any similar tutorial. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First you get all the links from `li.#Selected a`, then you make a loop to get `div.InfoD` from each one...

Here's a code snippet showing how:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$url = "http://www.blabla.com/";

$baseUrl= "http://www.blabla.com"

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a URL
$html->load_file($url);

// Get all links
$anchors = $html->find('li.#Selected a');

// loop through each link and get the node having "InfoD" class
// Everytime make sure to clear dom objects to avoid memory leaks
foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {

    // Create the new link to parse
    $urlTemp = $baseUrl . $anchor->href;

    //Create a DOM object
    $html2 = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a URL
    $html2->load_file($urlTemp);

    // Get all nodes with "text-logo"
    $div = $html->find('div.InfoD', 0);

    echo $div;
    echo "<hr/>";

    // Clear dom object
    $html2->clear(); 
    unset($htm2);

}

// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

Comment: what would be the best way to simply automatically follow the links and scrape full content from the detail pages?